# Continous data prediction with all categorical features analysis

Tags: python, regression, data-science, data-analysis, categorical-data

I have a case where I want to predict columns H1 and H2 which are continuous data with all categorical features in the hope of getting a combination of features that give optimal results for H1 and H2, but the distribution of the categories is uneven, there are some categories which only amount to 1,

Heres my data :

[image]

and my information of categories frequency in each column:

[image]

what I want to ask:

1. Does the imbalance of the features of the categories greatly affect the predictions? what is the right solution to deal with the problem?
2. How do you know the optimal combination? do you have to run a  data test simulation predicting every combination of features with the created model?
3. What analytical technique is appropriate to determine the relationship between features on H1 and H2? So far I'm converting category data using one hot encoding and then calculating the correlation map
4. What ML model can be applied to my case? until now I have tried the RF, KNN, and SVR models but the RMSE score still high
5. What keywords that have similar cases and can help me to search for articles on google, this is my first time working on an ML/DS case for a paper.
   thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1. A prediction based on a single observation won't be too reliable, of course. Binning rare categories into a sort of 'other' category is one common approach.
2. Feature selection is a vast topic (g: filter methods, embedded methods, wrapper methods). Personally I prefer studying mutual information and variance inflation factor first.
3. We cannot rely on Pearson's correlation when talking about categorical or binary features. The basic approach would be grouping your dataset by categories and comparing the target distributions for each one, running statistical tests perhaps to check whether the difference is significant. Also g: ANOVA, Kendall rank.
4. That said, preprocessing your data to get rid of useless or redundant features often yields much more improvement than using more complex models or hyperparameter tuning. Regardless, trying out gradient boosting models never hurts (catboost even provides a robust automatic handling of categorical features). ExtraTreesRegressor is less prone to overfitting than classic RF. Linear models should not be ignored either, especially ones like Lasso with embedded feature selection capability.

Comment: so for point two what i looking for is feature selection? i thought feature selection only for picking best feature for better training. so how do i achieve what best category for each column which give best H1 or/and H2 with feature selection?